# SQL join on multiple Rows to Single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am struggling to do a join in the way that I need, I have two tables that house data I need to link(just to be clear). One table holds Outbound Call data, number dialed, duration ect. the other table holds contact details of the people dialed. Set out as below:

```
CustID | Number 1  | Number 2 | Number 3  | Number 4
    1  | 072454584 |          | 017726593 | 
    2  |           |0125456852|           | 0125785448
```

So if we wanted to call Customer 1 we would try both numbers, with only one connecting.

What i need to do is join the number dialed to the customer records but so that it compares each number till it matches match (hoping this makes sense). I've tried a `case when` Statement but it didn't work. Whats the best approach in doing this?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably take this approach to the query.

```
with myphones
AS
(
    SELECT CustomerId, Phone1 As Phone FROM ContactDetails
    UNION
    SELECT CustomerId, Phone2 As Phone FROM ContactDetails
    UNION
    SELECT CustomerId, Phone3 As Phone FROM ContactDetails
    UNION
    SELECT CustomerId, Phone4 As Phone FROM ContactDetails
)
SELECT p.CustomerId, p.Phone, oc.*
FROM myphones p 
    INNER JOIN outboundcalls oc ON p.Phone = oc.Phone
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a series of left outer join's with a conditional statement on the match:

```
select cd.CustId,
       coalesce(oc1.number, oc2.number, oc3.number, oc4.number) as MatchingNumber,
       (case when oc1.Number is not null then 'Number1'
             when oc2.Number is not null then 'Number2'
             when oc3.Number is not null then 'Number3'
             when oc4.Number is not null then 'Number4'
        end) as WhichMatch
from ContactDetails cd left outer join
     OutboundCalls oc1
     on cd.number1 = oc1.number left outer join
     OutboundCalls oc2
     on cd.number2 = oc2.number left outer join
     OutboundCalls oc3
     on cd.number3 = oc3.number left outer join
     OutboundCalls oc4
     on cd.number4 = oc4.number;
```

The `left outer join` attempts to match to each number in the list.  The `coalesce()` will choose the first matching number, and the `case` tells you which number matches.

Note that if you have multiple successful outbound calls for a given customer, you will get multiple rows in the output.